# Simplified example using Rcpp to link an object file to a function

Tags: rcpp

I have existing C code that consists of three files: a header file ( a ".h" file), a library file (a ".o" file), and a source file. They currently run under UNIX and as compiled "mex files" in Matlab. I would like to port them to R using Rcpp. They are all long and complex, so I made a minimal example to help me understand how to port them to R.

The simplified header file (my_header.h) is:

```
typedef unsigned int    ui4;
ui4  add_one( ui4 );
```

The simplified "library" file (my_lib.cpp) is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "my_header.h"

ui4 add_one(ui4 x) {
        return(x+1);
}
```

The simplified function program (my_program.cpp) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>

#include "my_header.h"

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
ui4 my_program_r () {
//int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
//
// As a MATLAB mex file, this function calls "main(..."
//
  ui4 value = add_one( (ui4)1 );
  printf( "%d", value );
  return value;
}
```

From the terminal (I'm on a Mac), I can compile these without an error:

```
$ g++ my_lib.cpp -c -o my_lib.o
$ g++ my_program.cpp -o my_program my_lib.o
```

When I try to compile them in RStudio, I get:

```
> library(Rcpp)
> sourceCpp( "my_program.cpp" )
Warning message:
In sourceCpp("my_program.cpp") :
  No Rcpp::export attributes or RCPP_MODULE declarations found in source
>
```

Why isn't this compiling under Rcpp? How do I specify the linked file (the ".o" library file) in the "sourceCpp" command? Do I need to specify the header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sourceCpp` command is meant for single files only. If you have multiple files, you have to use a package:

- Call `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton(...)` to create a skeleton package.
- Copy `*.h`, `*.c` and `*.cpp` to the `src` folder.
- Call `Rcpp::compileAtrributes()`.
- Use `R CMD build ...`, `R CMD check ...` and `R CMD INSTALL ...` to build, check and compile the package. (The `check` will complain about undocumented functions ...)

For more details see [Rcpp-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf) vignette and for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354302/rcpp-sourcecpp-undefined-symbol). BTW, since R does not have an `unsigned int` type, I am not sure if your return value will work. You might have to switch to an `int` or `double`. I also get a different error message than you:

> Error in dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpSbvXHx/sourceCpp-i686-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.17/sourcecpp_625ad24a943/sourceCpp_2.so") : 
>     unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpSbvXHx/sourceCpp-i686-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.17/sourcecpp_625ad24a943/sourceCpp_2.so':
>     /tmp/RtmpSbvXHx/sourceCpp-i686-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.17/sourcecpp_625ad24a943/sourceCpp_2.so: undefined symbol: _Z7add_onej

Are you sure the above code is exactly what you used?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact code that I attempted to compile. I'm using Mac OS Sierra and R version 3.4, if that helps. Your answer and the answer to the previous question (which I assume you noted) appear to be the way to go. Thank you, also, for the advice regarding unsigned int values! The work-around when porting to Java is to use the signed version of "the next int up", so I will try signed "int 8".

Comment: `unsigned int` will be magically converted to `integer()` in _R_, which is _signed_.